Batch rename files in a certain directory (remove prefixes)
I have a folder on Windows with pictures from various messengers, each with their own format. Some prefix IMG_, some image-, and my own pictures don't use any prefix. I want to write a script that cuts these and other prefixes. Example:
before: IMG_20220130_002520_211
after: 20220130_002520_211
I feel like I am close to the solution, only for some reason the code below gets the FileNotFoundError:
import os
path = "d:/MyName/Pictures/test"
files = os.listdir(path)
for i, filename in enumerate(files):
    if filename.startswith("IMG_"):
        print(filename.removeprefix("IMG_"))
        os.rename(filename, filename.removeprefix("IMG_"))

The print command print(filename.removeprefix("IMG_")) does work just fine and returns exactly what I want. It is just the renaming part that will not work. What am I missing here?
PS: I have searched plenty of threads discussing this particular problem, but I could not get any of the suggestions running...
PPS: Once I get this snipped done, I will just add elif conditions for each subsequent prefix.

os.listdir() returns just the filenames, it does NOT include the full directory path.  So you need to include path in the old and new filenames.

is "d:/MyName/Pictures/test" a valid path on windows ?(NB: I have no windows experience - yes, really !)

@JohnGordon Thank you for the explanation, now I at least know why my code did not work! I basically altered a temporary variable (only the filename) rather than the path. os.rename then expects to be given a path, while I only hand over the variable/filename, therefore the error message.

@ticktalk It is! Since I have two drives I run the OS on C:\ and moved most of the user folders (pictures, documents etc.) to D:.

I would use pathlib for that:
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("d:/MyName/Pictures/test")

for item in path.iterdir():
    if item.name.startswith("IMG_"):
        print(item.name.removeprefix("IMG_"))
        item.rename(item.with_name(item.name.removeprefix("IMG_")))


fyi:that throws     item.rename(item.with_name(item.name.removeprefix("IMG_")))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'

That did it for me! Thank you so much! I would vote you up it I wasn't a noob. Maybe if somebody can vote up my question I have enough XP to be able to vote and return my thanks  I take away from this that path operations are better performed with the path library, I will research that more.

Just passed the threshold, here's my upvote :)

@ticktalk that method was added in Python 3.9. You can use subscripting or the trim method to achieve the same result.

thks, as everthing else appeared ok i'd presumed < 3.9, but appreciate you clarifying
